# Pandas grouping extremely slow for aggregations min and max

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe with datetime index, and shape:

```
df.shape
(311885, 38)
```

Aggregate functions .sum(), .mean() and .median() work fine:

```
%%time
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).mean()
CPU times: user 77.6 ms, sys: 16 ms, total: 93.7 ms
Wall time: 92.7 ms
```

However, .min() and .max() are extremely slow:

```
%%time
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).min()
CPU times: user 51.1 s, sys: 377 ms, total: 51.5 s
Wall time: 51.1 s
```

Also, tried resample with equally bad result:

```
%%time
df.resample('D').min()
CPU times: user 52.2 s, sys: 478 ms, total: 52.7 s
Wall time: 52.2 s
```

Installed versions:

```
pd.__version__
'0.25.2'
print(sys.version)
3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2019, 11:02:34) 
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]]
```

Is this expected behaviour? Can timings of .min() and .max() be improved?

Comment: It can be , just using drop_duplicate or duplicate

Comment: Do your data contain text/string? `mean, sum` will ignore them, but min, max don’t.

Comment: @QuangHoang I think `groupby` will not ignore strings for sum: `pd.DataFrame([['A', 'B']*2]*10).groupby(0).sum()`

Comment: Oh well, you got it! One column was string and when I removed it then min and max become fast! Thanks :)

Comment: @ALollz good point. Although string sum is even quicker than `int`/`float` sum in a way, so that probably doesn't count :-).

Comment: Eh it all depends. I've crashed a few kernels accidentally trying to `sum` several million IDs that were each 10-20 characters long. (thought they were in the index). `sum` becomes abysmal for many strings and will scale horribly with the length of the strings and the number of sums. `str.join` is faster

Answer (score 1):

As Quang Hoang pointed out in their comment, I had a string column which caused `.min()` and `.max()` to be slow. Without it, everything is fast.